# PHP Regex Help for parsing String

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string such as the following:

```
Are you looking for a quality real estate company? 

<s>Josh's real estate firm specializes in helping people find homes from          
[city][State].</s>

<s>Josh's real estate company is a boutique real estate firm serving clients 
locally.</s> 

In [city][state] I am sure you know how difficult it is
to find a great home, but we work closely with you to give you exactly 
what you need
```

I would like to have this paragraph split into an array based on the `<s> </s>` tags, so I have the following array as the result:

```
[0] Are you looking for a quality real estate company?
[1] Josh's real estate firm 
    specializes in helping people find homes from [city][State].
[2] Josh's real estate company is a boutique real estate firm serving clients 
    locally.
[3] In [city][state] I am sure you know how difficult it is
    to find a great home, but we work closely with you to give you exactly 
    what you need
```

This is a regex i'm currently using:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all(":<s>(.*?)</s>:is", $string, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
print_r($result);
```

But this one only returns an array containing the text found between `<s> </s>` tags, it ignores the text found before and after these tags. (In the example above it would only return the array elements 1 and 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I could get was using `preg_split()` instead:

```
$string = <<< STR
Are you looking for a quality real estate company? <s>Josh's real estate firm 
specializes in helping people find homes from [city][State].</s>
<s>Josh's real estate company is a boutique real estate firm serving clients 
locally.</s> In [city][state] I am sure you know how difficult it is
to find a great home, but we work closely with you to give you exactly 
what you need
STR;

print_r(preg_split(':</?s>:is', $string));
```

And got this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Are you looking for a quality real estate company? 
    [1] => Josh's real estate firm 
specializes in helping people find homes from [city][State].
    [2] => 

    [3] => Josh's real estate company is a boutique real estate firm serving clients 
locally.
    [4] =>  In [city][state] I am sure you know how difficult it is
to find a great home, but we work closely with you to give you exactly 
what you need
)
```

Except that produces an extra array element (index `2`) where there's a newline between the fragments `[city][State].</s>` and `<s>Josh's real estate company`.

It'd be trivial to add some code to remove the whitespace matches though, but I'm not sure if you desire that.

Comment: The extra array element is fine, but it seems to be looking for just `</s>`, which means that something like `my name is bob. im 17 </s>.` and `my name is bob. <s>im 17</s>` would both be split into 2 elements, can it be changed so the 1st example is kept in 1 array element only? (I'd like unopened `</s>` to not be matched).

Comment: Also if the empty array elements could be removed, then i'd prefer it.

Comment: I'll fiddle with my code for a bit, then update my answer if I'm able to match only properly opened-and-closed tags, and to remove empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into DOM
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php